# Rewriting Sysctl output to a file in NetBSD

Tags: shell, bsd

I am writing a script, while alloting a kernel memory thro' kmem_zalloc() the return address is a pointer and I can't able to capture in any mode. Redirecting to standard output didn't work. how to write this into a file, or to some environment variable. Anyway storing the return address didn't works. Very peculiar.

## sysctl -n -w ddb.command="call kmem_zalloc(240,1)"0xf7bdb858

It directly prints next to the command I typed. How to get the address into script as variable or a file.

Thanks,
Paavaanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
result=$(sysctl -n -w ddb.command="call kmem_zalloc(240,1)")
```

or if your shell is older, you may need to use

```
result=`sysctl -n -w ddb.command="call kmem_zalloc(240,1)"`
```

Then you can do:

```
echo $result
0xf7bdb858
```